# Is it possible to gain weight while training for marathon

Tags: running, training, weight-gain

I'm training 4 days a week to gain weight; some mass. But i'm also running 3 days a week to prepare for a marathon.

Will I be able to gain some weight while running. I eat a lot of calories, carbs ... well everything that's good to put on some mass.

Thanks

Comment: ultimately gaining weight is all about eating more than you are burning, so i would imagine that it's possible, however it would require a huge amount of food.

Comment: Yeah, I've gain weight 2 first week starting my training, but after that i've started running, still gaining a little weight, don't know if someone have a trick i'm already eating a lot : food + shake

Comment: well if you are still gaining weight then you shouldn't worry as you only need to be gaining about a pound a week not more.

Comment: Yeah but it's not even a pound a week, it's more like a pound a month, so I need some trick

Comment: only 3 days a week to run 26.2 miles?

Comment: Sorry I've used the term maraton but i'm preparing for a 6 miles obstacle race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pick one. Either gain weight and stop running so much, or keep running and give up trying to gain weight. If you eat gobs and gobs of food you might be able to sustain a slow rate of gain--a pound a month sounds fine--but why would you expect significant mass gains if you're undermining them three times a week?

I might even back off to three days of weight training instead of four. Many mass gain protocols involve a lot less activity (just short, intense, heavy lifting) and a lot more rest and eating.

Answer (score 1):

There's no trick, just eat more. A lot of people who have trouble gaining weight choose milk as an easy extra source of calories. Milk has a high amount of fat and protein.